# how to get sum of numbers in javascript of hidden fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some dynamic input hidden fields with class "absclass".I have both numbers and 
   characters in these fields.
   I want to get the sum of only numbers in javascript.I have written like below and that is
   not working.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btn').live('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var sum = 0;
            $('.absclass').each(function() {
                sum += Number($(this).val());
            });
            $("#sum").html(sum); 
        });                              
    });
```

Please tell me why it is not working?

**EDIT** : HTML code

```
<td><input type="hidden" class="absclass" id="txtsp<?php echo $p; ?>" value=""/></td>
```

below is the script.In this on button click i am passing values to hidden fields and also
   getting their sum simultaneously.So that only values passed to fields but when i go for

second time click then the sum coming.

```
        <script>
    var arr = new Array();
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var txt1 = $('#txt1').val();
            var txt2 = $('#txt2').val();
            var txt3 = $('#txt3').val();
            var txt4 = $('#txt4').val();
            var txt5 = $('#txt5').val();
            var txt6 = $('#txt6').val();
            var textbox1 = $('#textbox1').val();
            var textbox2 = $('#textbox2').val();
            var textbox3 = $('#textbox3').val();
            var textbox4 = $('#textbox4').val();
            var textbox5 = $('#textbox5').val();
            var textbox6 = $('#textbox6').val();
            $.post("matchanswers.php", {"txt1": txt1, "txt2": txt2, "txt3": txt3, "txt4": txt4, "txt5": txt5, "txt6": txt6, "textbox1": textbox1, "textbox2": textbox2, "textbox3": textbox3, "textbox4": textbox4, "textbox5": textbox5, "textbox6": textbox6}, function(data) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
          <?php for ($k = 0; $k < 6; $k++) { ?>
                    $('#txtspan<?php echo $k; ?>').html(obj[<?php echo $k; ?>]);
                    $('#txtsp<?php echo $k; ?>').val(obj[<?php echo $k; ?>]);
//                        $(".hide").css( "display", "block");
//                        $(".answertext").css( "display", "none");
            <?php } ?>
            });
            var sum = 0;
            $('.absclass').each(function() {
                var val = Number($(this).val());
                if (!isNaN(val)) {
                    sum += val;
                }
            });
            $("#sum").html(sum);
        });
             });
       </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: The sum i am getting only 0

Comment: show us your html as well

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: <td><input type="hidden" class="absclass" id="txtsp<?php echo $p; ?>" value=""/></td>

Comment: If you have characters and numbers, `parseInt` or `parseFloat` might help.

Comment: @user1755949 so... your input have empty value

Comment: your hiden field's value is empty ?

Comment: i am adding values to hidden fields and after that getting the sum

Comment: @user1755949 how do you adding values to hidden fields?

Comment: check your value first with the isNaN function before adding it to sum (cfr my answer)

Comment: Some words of advice: **Please stop using `live` and `bind`**...

Comment: @KamranAhmed or stop update jquery :-)

Answer (score 1):

The .live() method is deprecated (jQuery 1.7). Use .on() instead.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="btn" id="btn">
<input type="hidden" value="1" class="absclass">
<input type="hidden" value="2" class="absclass">
<input type="hidden" value="3" class="absclass">
<input type="hidden" value="4" class="absclass">
<input type="hidden" value="5" class="absclass">    
</form>
<div>Total: <span id="sum"></span></div>    
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var sum = 0;
        $('.absclass').each(function() {
            sum += Number($(this).val());
        });
        $("#sum").html(sum); 
    });                              
});    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `deprecated` not the same `removed`, _version deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9_

Answer (score 0):

if each of these fields contain a value (numeric plus character, I assume, you can get the numeric values using parseInt:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
   var sum = 0;
            $('.absclass').each(function() {
                sum += parseInt($(this).val());
            });
            $("#sum").html(sum); 
        });                              
    });
```

Comment: if i am using parseInt it is showing NaN.For that i have used isNaN.That also not working

Comment: Check your input field in firebug if it really contains any value? I'm sure it is blank, that's why it's showing NaN.

Comment: Don't forget to pass the base to your parseInt function `parseInt(number, base)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the value to an int. Then you can check if the value is a number and add it to sum if it is (inside your each):

```
var val = parseInt($(this).val());
if(!isNaN(val)){
    sum += val;
}
```

---

**EDIT:** After seeing that you make use of $.post to fill the data make sure the code i located within the callback of this function (because only there you can be sure that the data is filled in and you can start making the sum).:

```
$.post("matchanswers.php", {"txt1": txt1, ...}, 
    function(data) {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
        <?php for ($k = 0; $k < 6; $k++) { ?>
             $('#txtspan<?php echo $k; ?>').html(obj[<?php echo $k; ?>]);
             $('#txtsp<?php echo $k; ?>').val(obj[<?php echo $k; ?>]);
        <?php } ?>
        var sum = 0;
        $('.absclass').each(function() {
            var val = parseInt($(this).val());
            if (!isNaN(val)) {
                sum += val;
            }
        });
        $("#sum").html(sum);
    }
);
```

Comment: i got the issue.actually same time i am passing values to the hidden fields and getting the sum of their values.so first time it is not coming.But second time the sum is coming.So what can i do to for that?

Comment: @user1755949 how you passing values to the hidden fields?

Comment: on that same button click through jquery

Comment: you need to add this code in your $.post behind the loop. Because this is where the values actually are loaded & filled in.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working fiddle : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/he8cm/)

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="ok">
 <input type="hidden" class="absclass" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" class="absclass" value="2"> 
<input type="hidden" class="absclass" value="3">  
<div id="sum"></div>
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btn').live('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
   var sum = 0;
            $('.absclass').each(function() {
                  if(!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) sum += Number($(this).val());
            });
            $("#sum").html(sum); 
        });                              
    });
```

What is your version of jquery ? Because `live()` is deprecated

Comment: see comment to OP: jquery version 1.7.1

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
  $('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var sum = 0;
        $('.absclass').each(function() {
            var num = Number(this.value);
            if(!isNaN(num)){
                sum += num;
            }
        });
        $("#sum").html(sum); 
    });                              
});
```

Answer (score 0):

move your

```
var sum = 0;
$('.absclass').each(function() {
    var val = Number($(this).val());
    if (!isNaN(val)) {
        sum += val;
    }
});
$("#sum").html(sum);
```

into post callback like this

```
$.post("matchanswers.php", {"txt1": txt1, "txt2": txt2, "txt3": txt3, "txt4": txt4, "txt5": txt5, "txt6": txt6, "textbox1": textbox1, "textbox2": textbox2, "textbox3": textbox3, "textbox4": textbox4, "textbox5": textbox5, "textbox6": textbox6}, 
    function(data) {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
        for (var k = 1; k < 7; k++) { 
            $('#txtspan'+k).html(obj[k]);
            $('#txtsp'+k).val(obj[k]);
        }
        var sum = 0;
        $('.absclass').each(function() {
            var val = Number($(this).val());
            if (!isNaN(val)) {
                sum += val;
            }
        });
        $("#sum").html(sum);
    }
);
```

in your code you try calc sum before get answer from server and set value for your hidden fields
also see more about [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) function, it send **asynchronous** request